# Progressively filter lists across columns

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu, filtering

I have a table that consists of 3 columns and 6 rows, each column has a separate drop down list assigned to the rows below it that is pulling the data from a 'master' inventory list on a separate sheet. I want the the list in column B cells to be filtered by the selection made in column A cells and so forth with column C cells dependent on the column B selection.

Unsure what tags to use for this.

[This is the form that I want to do the filtering lists across 'type', 'size' and 'serial #'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MWQO.png)

[This is a basic layout of how I want the inventory list to look and where the data from the lists will be pulled from. I would like one list rather than multiple tables so that it is easy to add and remove tooling. Floor operators are the ones that will be keeping up this list which is I want it to be as basic as I can make it, if possible.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM5yQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because I do not have enough rep but please see this link on how to create dependant lists using data validation.

https://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

Comment: I have tried this method of making the 'named ranges' but I have too many individual inventory items (100's) and I would have to make to make a ridiculous amount of tables. Also, it would not let me use the characters I need in the 'range names'. The items I am trying to inventory are tooling pieces for machines.